# Is it outside my bounds as a non-moderator to remind people to be civil?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, community-moderation

I found an answer on Meta that, at the time, included the text:

> Don't respond to trash like that with code solutions.

I commented:

> Just because the question was close-worthy (as evidenced by the fact that it has been removed from the site) doesn't mean you should call the asker "trash". Please keep your civility about you, on main **and** meta.

Someone replied, pointed out that I have no diamond next to my name and requested that I not pretend to be a moderator (they also corrected my misinterpretation of the antecedent of "trash", but that is irrelevant here).

I don't think I used any language that pretends to be a moderator, but I could certainly be wrong, and I certainly don't want to participate in [impersonation](https://definitions.uslegal.com/c/criminal-impersonation/), so I thought I'd get some more eyes on this to answer:

1. In my specific case, could I have done something to avoid impersonating a mod (or coming across that way)?
2. In general, should we ordinary people be reminding each other about civility, or should we just wait and let mods say that?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191192/discussion-on-question-by-nh-is-it-outside-my-bounds-as-a-non-moderator-to-remi).

Comment: Do you know whether they were referring to the OP, rather than the post, as trash?

Comment: Don't wait for a moderator to call someone out on their BS. Once bitten, twice shy. If a user has to wait for a mod to step in every time they need cautioning, they'd be suspended pretty quickly. OTOH, for a repeat offender, a flag might be more appropriate.

Comment: @canon: This was answered in the original discussion that has since been moved to chat (for good reason).

Comment: Worth noting: in many cultures, it's unusual to prefix an instruction with "please" outside of formal contexts or demands. My experience as a Brit is that Brits mostly soften instructions for politeness by framing them as questions - "Would you mind doing X?", "Could you do X?", "Do you reckon you could X?" - but *not* by prefixing with "please". The latter, to my sensibilities, often sounds overly formal and like you are trying to assert authority over the target. This can lead to unfortunate misunderstandings if someone adds "please" to try and be polite, and others read it as adversarial.

Comment: Related: [Is a comment telling someone not to answer constructive?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348633/is-a-comment-telling-someone-not-to-answer-constructive)

Comment: Both comments should be flagged as Unfriendly or Unkind for being condescending and rude.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

> Someone replied, pointed out that I have no diamond next to my name and requested that I not pretend to be a moderator

They are completely, unequivocally, 100% wrong.

SO is a *community driven* site. Which means that the WHOLE community works towards making it better experience for all.

The [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) itself states:

> Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's ***built*** and ***run*** by ***you*** as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With ***your*** help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.

(emphasis mine)

> In my specific case, could I have done something to avoid impersonating a mod (or coming across that way)?

You were not impersonating a moderator so don't worry. Mods are very easily distinguishable due to their diamond.

> In general, should we ordinary people be reminding each other about civility, or should we just wait and let mods say that?

Eh, this is a double edged sword.

Sometimes, if you call someone out, the potential exists for it to turn into an argument and through said calling out, they might also be given the opportunity to vent their frustration or anger out on you. Not to mention the back-and-forth that ensues in the comments which can be completely avoided.

On the other hand, calling people out like that makes it clear to them, the OP, and the wider audience that inappropriate behaviour *is not* and *will not* be tolerated.

Though, if you are hesitant to call someone out, flag it so a mod can follow it up.

<sub>Anecdotally, I had a [similar incident](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357034/was-i-wrong-to-call-out-a-link-only-answer) a while back. You'll always have a group of people who have an issue with authority *even* if *they* are in the wrong.</sub>

Comment: "Anecdotally, I had a similar incident a while back." Oh look, [it's me in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357034/was-i-wrong-to-call-out-a-link-only-answer#comment517241_357034)!

Comment: @BoltClock it sure is, consistent as ever.

Comment: And well yeah flag it so mod can follow up. Which eventually got declined and no follow up :)

Comment: And you will always have a group of people who back authority when they are clearly wrong too (not that that is evident here). Sigh.

Comment: @Joshua you are quite correct.

Answer (score 53):

> In general, should we ordinary people be reminding each other about civility, or should we just wait and let mods say that?

The user who asked you to not impersonate a moderator, is perhaps not aware of [the Stack Overflow Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/):

> Stack Overflow is run by you!

You *are* a moderator, I *am* a moderator, we *all* are moderators here. Every user on Stack Overflow should help to moderate the content. The diamond moderators are there as exception handlers only!

Reminding users to be civil in comments is not an issue at all. But first, remember to flag the rude comments! This will allow the rude comment to be deleted, and also help us take some actions on that user, if they are a repeat offender. (Also just address the discussion as such, and not the user, as it might look like a personal attack)

That said, do spend a minute to first think about the situation. Sometimes the comment section would have been heated beyond a point, where "Calm Down! Be Nice!" is like throwing mentos in a bottle of coke. In those situations, avoid getting into the debate, and flag the entire section away.

Comment: I agree that we all moderate the site, but suggesting we're all moderators can be confusing and it's an area of confusion that many users have when making accusations against "moderators" who are high rep users. For the sake of clarity I'd not use the term moderators to describe all users. My tens cents ;)

Comment: You get to be a mod, you get to be a mod, you get to be a mod, you all get to be a mod!!

Comment: Call them "curators" instead.

Answer (score 29):

Back in the BBS days, there was a term called "backseat moderating", or "backseat modding" for short. Backseat modding is when a regular user tries to moderate or otherwise assert authority that only a moderator can effectively enforce, like making (often empty) threats that someone is going to get banned or their thread is going to get locked or deleted. In other words, moderating from the back seat, where you act like you're the one driving but you really aren't. This would often but not always be accompanied by a false sense of self-importance.

This isn't a case of backseat modding though. This is just you advising a fellow member to be civil. Anyone can advise their peers this way. It's not even moderation, it's being human, recognizing the other human, and treating the situation as what it is: an interpersonal conflict. At most, perhaps the user perceived your comment as sounding pompous — that sort of perception is not uncommon. But I personally don't see a problem with the tone of your comment.

Furthermore, as others are familiar with, Stack Overflow is founded on the principle that anyone can contribute to moderation. Yet, while most of the userbase has access to some or more tools to deal with problematic content, none of these tools deal with problematic *user conduct*. Users without a diamond can't enforce much against other users; their actions generally only affect the content other users post (and, indirectly, their [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans)).

So, on Stack Overflow, it only becomes backseat modding when you try to intimidate or antagonize the other person by

- threatening to flag or declaring that you have flagged their content (seriously, anyone who does this, stop, you're only embarrassing yourself, not impressing us),
- saying things like "I will make sure you get banned" or "your post is going to get closed/deleted", or indeed,
- pretending to be a moderator: speaking like one, using "we" to refer to a group of people you're not a part of, claiming you are privy to any information that only moderators have access to, etc. (To clarify, it's OK to explain on meta what you understand about the privileges diamond users have and the work they do, as long as you don't claim to be one of them.)

Your moderation duty as a non-moderator is to

- use your votes and flags in situations you feel you can use your best judgement,
- delegate to others in situations you feel you can't that don't require our intervention, and
- delegate to us in exceptional situations you feel that moderator intervention is necessary.

Educating others on what to do and what not to do doesn't really count as moderation to me, because you aren't enforcing anything by doing so. It's the flags you raise — the communication you initiate with us — that count as moderation actions. And as long as you don't send the message that you're personally going to make sure someone else's content or behavior is going to be addressed, you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: this is a good answer. It's good to have people stand up and say "don't be rude" the problem is, it often leads to arguments and doesn't achieve the desired result. If in doubt don't say anything and flag. People often don't take kindly to criticism and if they're being rude, it's even more likely they'll react to a comment telling them to be nice in a rude manner.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term Backseat modding, but my gut feeling when I read your answer was it seems like the natural abbreviation for someone doing it would be a BS Mod, which made me chuckle. Were they ever referred to as BS Mods?

Comment: @DavyM yeh, I was on the border of wondering the same thing. Made me smile too :)

Comment: @Davy M: Not that I recall, no. Missed opportunity there. But on one BBS I was in where the slightest infractions got 1-day bans it was always funny to see "User was banned for this post. Reason: backseat modding" (usually sounding much snarkier than that)

Comment: I feel like there's a difference between (1) a reminder to be nice and (2) a threat of ban for not being nice. I would stand behind the former, and would cringe at the latter.

Comment: The thing about criticising people's conduct in the comments is that it inevitably becomes an "exceptional situation", since you're then leaving behind rapidly-obsolete confrontational comments about a matter tangential to the actual post the comments are under, and those then require moderator action to clear up. I tend to prefer to just flag non-constructive, borderline-rude comments as "no longer needed" than to wade into a comment argument that will increase the cleanup work y'all need to do - especially when I can't speak from a position of authority and will likely be ignored anyway.

Answer (score 13):

Stack Overflow is a community-moderated site, and you should absolutely feel free to contribute to that moderation effort. The notion that a user should hold their tongue because they don't have enough rep or because they aren't a diamond moderator is absurd.

By the same token, your assertion that

> my misinterpretation of the antecedent of "trash", but that is irrelevant here

is not irrelevant. Your automatic assumption of ad-hominem ill-will on the part of the commenter could be construed as insulting, especially since, as you note in comments, the commenter was in fact referring to the quality of the post.

Stack Overflow is a widely-diverse community; there are *many* viewpoints. It's much easier to get along if we assume goodwill unless and until subsequent events leave no doubt.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191191/discussion-on-answer-by-mark-benningfield-is-it-outside-my-bounds-as-a-non-moder).

Answer (score 5):

The full context is this:

- You write a post on meta and it turns controversial somehow. Before that, it has some +20 score.
- Then someone leaves an opinion-based and negative comment: "This should have been a comment". Various opinion-based arguing follows from both sides.
- Then someone productively stems in: "Correct, this is an inappropriate answer" (no rationale given why).
- Before you know it down votes start raining where people previously agreed at you. -30 all out of the blue. The meta (welcome) bandwagon has begun.
- Suddenly everyone is nagging at you from left to right, dissecting the post looking for something negative to say. It is no longer sharing opinions and giving some form of constructive criticism - this is no longer a discussion but a bandwagon.
- As the 10th person gets the idea to stem into the choir and also misinterpret what I said, I might possibly snap back, possibly without weighing my words all too carefully.

I can be pretty outspoken and borderline rude. But I wouldn't call another user trash - that referred to this question (quoted in its entirety):

> I’m trying to do 2 simple things but idk what/where to look. I need a rotating T-shirt and a blinking lights

Now this kind of bandwagon/sheep mentality bullying where everyone must think what the previous person said is obviously common on the internet and SO both. This is why you quietly should flag for diamond mod attention instead of starting/joining a crusade in comments. Nothing good will come out of the latter.

And that's where my comment of you not being a moderator came from.

Comment: Unrelated: does anyone know where I can get a rotating T-shirt with blinking lights? Unicorn motif preferred.

Comment: ... that is indeed, a trash question. literally good for the trash. wow. Hopefully nobody will say that this was somebody's "best effort". I believe this is why blanket statements such as "you should never use trash" are worthless. context exists, and matters, and in this case that question, deserves the qualification trash, in respect to what asking a question on SO is. this is not "bad", or "lacks effort", or "unclear", but trash.

Comment: I'm glad you got your view across, this happens too frequently on meta where the respective parties are not aware of something that is being discussed in regards to them so they don't get a chance to "defend" themselves. As far as the trash business goes, I would agree, that post *is* [trash](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20trash) i.e. a waste, useless.

Comment: Which makes me realize, is it possible a part of this situation is because some people see more into the word trash than what it means? Trash designates something that should go to the garbage. Nothing more, nothing less, and nothing *else*.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier the problem is not with the word per se as I mentioned in my comment at the top, it's the fact that *people* mistook it as though Lundin was calling the OP of that question trash.

Comment: [1/2] I kind of feel bad about what happens, somehow I fear I did initiate all this, with my wanted to be funny sarcastic comment with a dimmed reference to [a popular xkcd](https://xkcd.com/810/). Sounds like you didn't got it, and instead fall right into what I was trying to show you, that you still seem to miss today: Before your first bullet, there should be `• Someone asks "*Why the system does X*"?`. Your answer doesn't answer this question at all. You even replied to my comment stating "*I have no idea why the OP couldn't post their code*". That's the only problem with your answer:

Comment: [2/2] It is not answering the question. I am really sorry that humans have this tendency to make things escalate until they blow out, that wasn't my intention at all, and I ask you to accept my apologies. Now, all it would have taken to avoid it was to add a disclaimer in the answer itself: "*I don't know why you weren't able to post your answer, but in this particular case [your answer here]*".

Comment: "Then someone productively stems in: "Correct, this is an inappropriate answer" (no rationale given why)." This is false; rationale was given by several people in several comments. Maybe you missed them (there were 3 or 4 of them), but just FYI this answer is inaccurate when it claims "full context" in its current review of events.

Comment: @TylerH That's exactly my point. Since 3 or 4 had already responded with arguments, why does person number 5 have to post a comment "this is an inappropriate answer" without adding anything to the discussion? That's the very bandwagon behavior I'm talking about.

Comment: @Lundin Possibly because you hadn't provided a response to the first 3 or 4? Just a guess.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier "trash" has been used in the U.S. to derogatorily describe people as being "of poor quality", mostly as the term "white trash". As far as I know, the origin was in the South, meaning Caucasian people who farmed their own land, usually without slave labor, were not part of "high society" and barely managed to get by financially. The use of the term has continued to this day. I most recently encountered it in an episode of the "Big Bang" where Penny's family referred to it and indirectly applied it to themselves (for laughs).

Comment: @CindyMeister lets not use a poorly written sitcom as a frame of reference

Comment: @CindyMeister but context matters, the sitcom is meant to be humorous and they are talking about people, Lundin wasn't, he was talking about content and more specifically regarding how useless it is, meaning, it won't help any future individuals. As mentioned above, if you pull a single word out of context and then analyse it, you'll be able to come up with any number of flaws with it.

Comment: @Cindy The US is but a small, small portion of English speakers on Earth. Their local quirks are of no concern to how we should use English on the internet. Trash designates something that should go to the trash...

Comment: Thanks for providing the context. I'm sorry to be the straw that broke the camel's back, so to speak.  And I feel your frustration.  I, too, have experienced that rain of down-votes.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I only provided the information because you asked: "Which makes me realize, is it possible a part of this situation is because some people see more into the word trash than what it means?" Should I have simply said "Yes" rather than provide the context as to *why*? I in no way imply that using the term is incorrect or a problem, as some people seem to feel I was trying to do...

Comment: @CindyMeister Ah, thanks for the clarification. I did not make the association between your comment and my initial one. Now that you mention it, it seems obvious. Retroactive thanks on answering my actual open question!