# Is it plagiarism if I'm not sure it was intentional?

Tags: support, review-queues

This appeared in the "first posts":

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/23969989

At first glance, this looks like an answer, but then there is the strange "thank you" at the end.

Reading the comments, it is clear that the answer was provided in the comments. The author of this answer copied and pasted, then added a "thank you" note.

I don't know how to review it. It's not really a "thank you" answer, and it's not obviously "low quality" because it actually solves the problem. I thought of flagging this for moderation attention, and marking as plagiarism. However this could be just a case of a newbie who wanted to say "thanks" but didn't have enough reputation.

Eventually I just skipped. But I'd like the community opinion. What should I have done here?

Comment: The comment suggested two approaches. One of them worked for the OP. They should have self-answered with the correct approach as suggested in the comment. Since they didn't, someone else did. What's to flag?

Comment: Isn't it plagiarism if you copy a comment and post as your own answer?

Comment: It is. The answer must contain a link to the original comment as source.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/6296561

Comment: @Zoe sounds like a plan

Answer (score 11):

OK so this is a tough one.

Normally, we treat answers that look like they were stolen from other answers, but contain an explicit thank-you message at the end, as thank-you answers, not plagiarism. This is because the thank-you message serves as *enough* of an indication that the poster is disclaiming authorship of the content and hence not trying to pass it off as their own. [Is explicit citation of the original comment still missing? Sure.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/answers-entirely-copied-though-properly-attributed/321326#321326) (The answer clearly thanked the comment author by name though, which is as good as it gets.) But in my ongoing effort to be more welcoming to new contributors, I'm comfortable special-casing thank-you answers.

Now, we also understand that these can be really hard to spot and can look remarkably like stolen content at first glance. So, even if someone were to flag such an answer as plagiarism... I guess I wouldn't blame them? I mean, even we moderators fail to spot these things sometimes and mistakenly treat them as the serious offense that plagiarism otherwise is. And the consequences for *our* actions are far greater than those of yours, since [your job is simply to flag issues for us to look into](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382410/is-it-outside-my-bounds-as-a-non-moderator-to-remind-people-to-be-civil/382417#382417), and so you shouldn't be implicated in any way.

But this is a thank-you answer copying not from an existing answer, but a comment, because no answer exists. First off, generally, if someone is posting thanks as an answer, they probably don't (or don't know to) distinguish comments and answers. That's their prerogative, and for that reason alone I'm not about to treat this as plagiarism either.

So the question becomes how *we* the community should handle these types of cases. Usually if no answer exists except in the comments then the content is fair game. However it is considered good manners to make your answer — should you post one for the sake of completing the question — a community wiki to symbolize that you don't take personal credit for the solution. And also credit the author in case the original comment goes away, which again the poster *did* to begin with.

I spent 2 minutes thinking about it after opening this meta question and decided that the easiest way out is to flag the answer for moderator attention with a custom flag, state as much as you can glean about the answer, and let us figure out the best course of action. Only moderators can toggle wiki on other people's answers, so even if you could clean up the answer (which, mind you, is fine to do), that's only half the job done depending on who you ask. If nothing else, flagging makes us *aware* of the answer to begin with, even if only for the few minutes of attention it needs, and I think that is the most important.

Comment: To answer the title: we do treat copied content as plagiarism by default. It's only when we find any clear indication that it was meant to be something else that we don't treat it as plagiarism. In 99% of cases, no such indication exists, even if in reality a good 50% of copied content came from harmless intent. But in most cases, this becomes a behavior *pattern*, which is when it becomes problematic. That's why we treat it so seriously.

Comment: "This is because the thank-you message serves as enough of an indication that the poster is disclaiming authorship of the content and hence not trying to pass it off as their own." Is this really enough to fulfill the attribution requirement of the content license? I'm not a lawyer but isn't one required to link to the original post. Additionally, I routinely remove simple "Thank you"s without any specific details from posts. I usually think they are just clutter.

Comment: @Trilarion: That is answered in the very next sentence... I even highlighted it by making it a link. Passing a work off as one's own, and failing to respect the content license, are two different issues.

Comment: @Trilarion: As for removing thank-you from posts because it is clutter... *the entire answer* is clutter, but by removing just that portion you're changing the nature of the answer completely, which as I've mentioned elsewhere is unfair to the poster. Remember that edits should not deviate from the author's intent. You need to make sure you're not just editing an original answer that inexplicably contains a thank-you note at the end (I've seen *many* of those, so I know they're out there).

Answer (score 3):

I see that the answer has now been edited with a link to the comment.

I question, however, whether this makes any sense. I think the "plagiarism" concern is being over-thought, here. Comments are volatile. If I came across this in any other queue I would mark any comment that contained information later included in an answer as "no longer needed". In that case the link no longer points anywhere.

If the answer is trivial (something "everyone" should know") I'd vote to close as "not reproducible".

If the information is useful to others in a search and one feels the person who made the original suggestion made a useful contribution and needs mentioning, then put their name in there.

Or, seeing how this answer is so short, re-write it to provide more information and so it's no longer "copy/paste".

Comment: Oh yeah, comments do disappear, so when it does the mention of the original comment can be removed from the answer. Still better to let it live with it for the time being, as the post from the would-be answerer was quite literally copying a comment in the answer dialog, which is orthogonally totally ok. Adding the link simply means "hey the op did not bother adding an answer, I'm doing it for them, kthxbai". I can't see any angle where we would not want that kind of information in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is a thank you answer, not plagiarism, I think.

The original poster wrote that as a comment, and someone with 1 reputation (I believe their only mean of interaction with anything on a question is answering) copied it with a thank you note.

Comment: Delete the "thank you" part and the answer stands on its own. Not a 'thank you' answer.

Comment: By all means @CinCout, please do edit it out, but right now, that's the content that sums the answer.

Comment: Hey, don't take it personal. They are just explaining how to analyze the answer. Ignore that last part and the tone of the answer changes. No one is telling you to actually go and edit anything.

Comment: @giusti Huh? editing stuff we see organically is paramount to the effort we make here on meta. We both have different visions, and I encouraged them to not only have the vision but also actually do stuff. That's the goal. Nothing personal anywhere in sight.

Comment: Removing the 'thank you' is a trivial edit. How to point out the obvious plagiarism is what I am concerned about.

Comment: Félix's answer is consistent with moderator policy, just FYI. It becomes plagiarism only when you remove the thanks and treat the answer as no longer being a thank-you answer. That's not very fair to the answer poster.

Answer (score -1):

It is definitely not a 'thank you' or a 'low quality' answer since it provides a solution, albeit copied from a comment posted by a different user. In another world, if I wrote such an answer, I would link to the original comment as source.

To answer your question, I would have also skipped the review since editing the answer to just add the source doesn't make sense to me. I would definitely have added a comment on the answer pointing out the same.

Comment: Well, we can't all skip. Sooner or later someone will have to deal with it. I'm thinking this should be flagged for moderation attention as "plagiarism". I shouldn't be asking myself it whether it was intentional or not.

Comment: That's my broad point @gusti. The idea is to evaluate how much human time is used up here discussing it, versus how much time it takes to cite the source and remove the noise.